# session cannot be resolved with jsp:useBean using tags

Tags: jsp, session

I am cleaning up some old code by using jsp tags.  For now I created a template tag which uses a footer tag and a header tag.  I moved the header and footer code out of `index.jsp` into the appropriate locations and I cleaned up all errors except one:

```
]] Root cause of ServletException.
weblogic.servlet.jsp.CompilationException: Failed to compile JSP /home/index.jsp
index.jsp:197:2: session cannot be resolved
<jsp:useBean id="myPojo" scope="session" class="my.pojo.MyPojo"/>

 ^---------^

    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JavelinxJSPStub.reportCompilationErrorIfNeccessary(JavelinxJSPStub.java:226)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JavelinxJSPStub.compilePage(JavelinxJSPStub.java:162)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspStub.prepareServlet(JspStub.java:246)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspStub.prepareServlet(JspStub.java:191)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:235)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

If I change the scope to request (`<jsp:useBean id="myPojo" scope="request" class="my.pojo.MyPojo"/>`), everything works fine.  However, changing scope on different beans isn't something that can be done right now.

When searching for this solutions, many people have mentioned this error when 
`<%@ page session="false"%>` is located on the page, but none of my pages have it.  I checked them all and I tried setting `session` to `true`, but that didn't do anything either.  Just to check my sanity I removed the tags and things work again, so the problem seems to be related to the combination of session scoped bean and tags.

I did some more testing and if I move `<jsp:useBean id="myPojo" scope="session" class="my.pojo.MyPojo"/>` from `index.jsp` to `template.tag` it works as well.

**template.tag**

```
<%-- template.tag -->
<%@ tag description="Base template" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html:html>
  <head>
    <!-- css includes -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <t:header renderTabs="${renderTabs}"/>
    <jsp:doBody/>
    <t:footer/>
    <!-- javascript includes -->
  </body>
</html:html>
```

**header.tag**

```
<%-- header.tag -->
<%@ tag description="Header" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ attribute name="renderTabs" required="true" type="java.lang.Boolean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<div>
```

**footer.tag**

```
<%-- footer.tag -->
<%@ tag description="Footer" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld" prefix="logic" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<div>
  <!-- render contact information -->
</div>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%-- index.jsp -->
<%@ page contentType="text/html" errorPage="/common/errors/error.jsp"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<t:template>
  <jsp:body>
    <jsp:useBean id="myPojo" scope="session" class="my.pojo.MyPojo"/>
    <!-- other code -->
  </jsp:body>
</t:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this, and it happens with `scope="application"` too.

It seems to be a bug/limitation of Weblogic (present as of 12.2.1.3.0). At least, it does not happen for me in Tomcat.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. StackOverflow is not a discussion form. If you are going to post an answer please make sure it is an answer. Please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to get a better understanding of what an answer is. Please also go through the site [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)